# jquery validate one of several passwords

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to build a simple validation script with Jquery but I am having difficulty.

I would like the entire body of my page apart from a simple user, company, password, 3 field form, to be hidden, until the person types in one of 5 potential passwords, then the body would become unhidden....

this seems quite easy with Jquery although I must be overthinking it. I also would like the passwords which I would just store as variables to be encrypted somehow...

does anyone have any suggestions?
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do solid encryption with javascript.

As for the hiding of the body except for the form, I'd use a CSS class on the body tag like this:

```
body.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then have your some descendant styles for you form:

```
body.hidden form {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Add and remove the class="hidden" using jquery when the password is matched.

Comment: php would provide solid encryption yes? 
does anyone know the code to have this class be removed if an input area equals one of several passwords???
i am not overly concerned with the security as this page will only be viewed by a select few people...
I will be tackling the security later, i just need to have this up and running and i thought it was an easy(er) approach.
so if it is possible....
could someone show me the code i would need to have a few passwords stored in an array maybe so if the password field has one of those typed it will remove a hidden class??
Please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do that as a method of unlocking some kind of admin functionality then it's very insecure.

Once you've sent the page content to the client, you can hide it, but anyone can just go and show it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on any client side javascript to limit what a user can see.  When it comes down to it, the user can either view the page source (or modify the html themselves) to view the data on the page... regardless of your password protection.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can hide the body with $("body").hide(); then listen for key-press events on the $(document).  Check the input variable and see if it contains the password you're looking for then show the $("body") and unbind the key-press listener

```
var input = '';
$("body").hide();
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    input += String.fromCharCode(e.which); // the character pressed on the the keyboard
    if(input == 'mypassword' || input == 'mypassword-1' || input == 'mypassword-2') { // would suggest using a timer here to reset the "input" var after 1 second or so of someone not typing
        $('body').show();
        $(document).unbind("keypress");
    }
});
```

Comment: The passwords, obviously, are visible in the JavaScript... so that's BAD, but, you could POST to a server-side password script that checks the password after every key-press, but that's BAD too, I was just humoring the question really... in general, you would use a server-side script language to bar access to the page unless a user had a verified user account with privileges to the page you are serving up

Comment: thanks!
but how can i target a specific input field?
i think this would just catch any keyboard input right?

Comment: Target a specific input field with $("input#ID_OF_INPUT").  But, a user would need to focus on that field for the key-press event listener to get triggered.  I added the even-listener to $(document) so it would catch the event from anywhere in the document